# Google Analytics API began to issue an error 403 insufficient Permissions (PHP)

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

It worked fine till January 10th but then have broken. Nobody hasn't change any permissions. I don't know the reason and can't find the answer.
If anybody could help me, please, don't be shy )

Server answer: `{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."}],"code":403,"message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."}}`

**Below is the graphic of requests to the API**
[image]

Comment: try with a new user and see if that works, if it does than is really that this user doesn't have permissions.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help.

Comment: did work with other user or not?

Comment: It doesn't work with other user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works!! 
New user were added to Google Analytics(not to developer console) and it's go work.

I don't know the reason, maybe it were working without the user because of bug or someone from our team has killed the user in analytics.
I think that it the second variant.